# How to Remove Prefix & Suffix from admin Customer Account Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, prefix, suffix

I want to remove Prefix and Suffix from the Customer Information tab in the admin section.

Can any tell me how to remove both from the admin customer tab?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

open file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Account.php

in foreach loop at line number 69 add below code

```
if($attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel()=='Prefix' || $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel()=="Suffix"){
                continue;
            }
```

https://drops.meetanshi.com/tw18fu

admin customer information tab is look like https://meetanshi.d.pr/ARTg0q